# Performance issue observed while using Spring AMQP ( SimpleMessageListenerContainer )

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

we have been facing issue in using SimpleMessageListenerContainer in SpringAmqp which is taking lots of CPU cycles and time while sending a simple message,

Attached documents

Important Notes

We are setting two postprocessors , which does minmalistic work and making the ack mode as auto along with channel as transactional enabled while starting the SimpleMessageListenerContainer.

We are using SpringAMQP 1.4.3 and RabbitMQ 3.4.4, Erlang 17.4 with CentOS as its OS having Quad core Intel Xeon CPU processor @ 2.5 GHz processor along with 16GB of RAM

[image: CPU SPike]

[image: CPU Spike 2]

Comment: This analysis shows me no useful information that leads to an issue with the container. Further, `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` does not `publish` messages, so I have no clue what your first snippet is. Something else is calling `basicPublish()`. If you need help debugging your issue, I suggest you provide a small test case that exhibits the problem.